# How to resolve this error while installing VSCode in Kali Linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code, kali-linux

I get this error code while installing.
I have tried using 
`sudo apt intall ./<filename>.deb`

but it gives this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And also this:

`sudo dpkg -i code_1.30.2-1546901646_amd64.deb`

But it gives another error.

```
Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 340375 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.30.2-1546901646_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code (1.30.2-1546901646) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:
 code depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package code (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.61) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code
```

Even `sudo apt --fix-broken install` doesn't help.

Comment: You're not going to get much help with kali Linux problems on SE. Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me for why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libgconf as the error states. You can find a deb for it [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libgconf-2-4) or use apt:

```
sudo apt install gconf
```